# Is the "static initialization order fiasco" a concern for constexpr variables?

Tags: c++, initialization, global-variables, constexpr

If I initialize a `constexpr` variable `foo` with a non-default value in one translation unit and then a initialize another `constexpr` variable `bar` with `foo` in another translation unit is it possible for `bar` to be initialized before `foo` resulting in a `bar` that was initialized by a zero-or-default-initialized `foo`. i.e. Unlike in the non-constexpr case (where the static initialization order fiasco is in effect) will the compiler and linker analyze dependency ordering to guarantee the correct result?

Additionally, how are constexpr variable templates affected? Their initialization ordering is undefined WITHIN single translation units.

C++17 standard answers preferred.

UPDATE:
Here is a minimal example. It works; that's the problem. At this point I'm 99% sure that this is safe from **[The Static Initialization Order Fiasco (TSIOF)](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order)**. However, due to the extreme, insidious nature of that problem I need to get confirmation that this is ok. I *believe* this code does not suffer from TSIOF since the inclusion of y.h in x.h orders `a` and `b` within the x.cc translation unit. However, AFAIU there are 2 translation units: one containing a, the other containing b. Furthermore, AFAI-sort-of-U a multiple definition of `a` error does not arise because the static keyword imparts internal *linkage* but `a` still has global *scope*.

compiled with:

```
clang++ -std=c++17 x.cc y.cc  #or g++
```

possible output:

```
in foo
```

possible output:

```
assertion failed (core dumped)
```

file x.cc:

```
#include "x.h"
int main(){ assert(b == 42); foo(); }
```

file x.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "y.h"
static constexpr int b = a+1;
```

file y.cc:

```
#include "y.h"
#include <iostream>
void foo(){
    std::cout << " in foo \n";
}
```

file y.h:

```
#pragma once
static constexpr int a=41;
void foo();
```

**Is this program guaranteed to output `in foo`?**

*Since this question can't be answered via example it really needs a language lawyer to provide relevant standard quotes*

This question is about STIOF across translation units. A related, unanswered question about STIOF within translation units for template variables is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401555/is-the-initialization-order-of-constexpr-i-e-constant-initialized-template-va)

Comment: How would you go about accessing a `constexpr` from another translation unit? That's kind of necessary for there to be a dependency to resolve.

Comment: The initialisation would not compile unless the compiler can resolve what the value is.   As such, it would not be possible for initialisation of `foo` to be invisible to the compiler when using it to initialise `bar`.

Comment: @Frank A `constexpr` variable can have external linkage, for example by using `extern constexpr` or by being a static class member.

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] giving an example of what you're doing (rather than a description of it)?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I posted a minimal, complete example. Verifiable is not possible due to the nature of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

In your example, there is no possible issue because the `a` in y.cc is a different variable from `a` in x.cc. So there is no cross-translation unit linkage happening.

In fact, there **cannot** be cross-translation unit linkage between constexpr variables. The whole point of `constexpr` is that the value is calculated at compilation time.

In other words, the constexpr must resolve to a value while we are still compiling the translation unit in isolation.

Because of the this the Static Initialization Order Fiasco implicitly does not apply to `constexpr` variables, and there is no need for the standard to mention what to do in that scenario.

Edit: as requested, the relevant part of the standard is 10.1.5 (9)[dcl.constexpr]

> In any constexpr variable declaration, the full-expression of the
>   initialization shall be a constant expression (8.20).

Which leads to 8.20 (1)  [expr.const] that has the following note:

> [ Note: Constant expressions can be evaluated during translation. — end note ]

Which is the rationale behind the next page and a half of clauses, but is enough by itself to preclude cross-translation unit references.

Comment: I am looking for confirmation my reasoning (in the UPDATE to the question) and references to prove it. This corroborates the speculating I did in the UPDATE so I'm up-voting. However, the original question is about proving from standard so I can't accept this answer.

Comment: @Lotney What else is there for the standard to say? The fiasco relates to cross-translation unit dependencies, and constexpr have to be fully resolved before the translation unit can be completed. They are mutually exclusive by definition.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is correct. However, to answer this question referenced quotations from the standard providing a chain of deduction defining the behavior in question are required.

Comment: @Lotney, I added references to the standard as you requested.

Comment: Yes, there is potentially a bit of difference between "can be" and "must be" that worries me about this.  constexpr provides a way to guarantee that the fiasco "can be" avoided, but I'm worried that this doesn't mean that all compilers "must" avoid it.

Comment: @PeterM It does not matter whether or not the compiler ultimately evaluates the constexpr during compilation or not. For it to be possible, there has to be enough information available. i.e. The result of the expression cannot depend on anything that lives in a different TU.