# Is the initialization order of constexpr (i.e. constant-initialized) template variables guaranteed?

Tags: c++, initialization, global-variables, language-lawyer, constexpr

From [en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization):

> Unordered dynamic initialization, which *[sic]* applies only to (static/thread-local) class template static data members and variable templates (since C++14) that aren't explicitly specialized.

Therefore static templates appear to be vulnerable to an even worse version of **[The Static Initialization Order Fiasco (TSIOF)](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order)** (i.e. unordered within a translation unit).

Does use of constexpr remove this vulnerability?

i.e. is the output of the below code **guaranteed** to be `success`?

Obviously, due to the nature of this question, working examples won't suffice as answers; quotes from the standard would be required.
(C++17 answers preferred)

```
#include<cassert>

template<class T> static constexpr T a = 41;
template<class T> static constexpr T b = a<T>+1;
int main(){
    assert(b<int> == 42);
    std::cout <<"success\n";
}
```

BTW, if someone is an expert on this I have a related, unanswered question (that would be easy for such an expert to answer) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381258/is-the-static-initialization-order-fiasco-a-concern-for-constexpr-variables).
Further, what would be the implications here if the answer to [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381258/is-the-static-initialization-order-fiasco-a-concern-for-constexpr-variables) is negative (i.e. constexpr doesn't help across translation units)?

UPDATE: I need to clarify what my concern is here. The original question title asked whether initialization order is a concern for constexpr template variables. I have clarified it. I am not concerned about whether dynamic initialization is taking place in the example; it isn't. My concern is that since ordered initialization cannot be assumed in the dynamic initialization case, can it be assumed in the constant initialization case? Prior to seeing the behavior of dynamically initialized template variables (within the same translation unit) I would have never even thought of this. However, since dynamically-initialized, static-duration template variables do not provide ordered initialization I now see no reason to assume that constant-initiliazed, static-duration template variables have guaranteed ordered initialization either. I need to be 100% sure that constant initialization of template variables takes place in the order of their definition within a TU.

Again, I see no reason to assume the constant-initializer-within-the-compiler is required to intialize in order if the dynamic initializer isn't. Absence of a warning in the standard that constant initialization is unordered does not suffice.

I realize that some may think this is excessive concern but I am working on safety-critical software and my company has placed adoption of C++14 on hold until this issue is resolved.

Comment: `constexpr` give a lot of guaranty as value should be known at compile time and no longer changes.

Comment: The quote explicitly states that initialization is unordered. i.e. not guaranteed.

Comment: You can even change your `assert` by `static_assert`.

Comment: The quote explicitly states that initialization is unordered. i.e. not guaranteed. I need a quote(s) from the standard that explicitly gives this guarantee. The main issue is that no proof of concept can answer this question. Code that suffers from TSIOF can work for years before producing really awful bugs. IMO it is *the* worst problem that C++ has. Prior to template variables I had been using the same-translation-unit solution. I didn't know about this issue with template variables. Luckily I saw bugs in code before release.

Comment: @Jarod42 static_assert is a great suggestion. A less paranoid individual might even accept it as a proof-of-concept. But I can't take any risks here. (I'd upvote but don't have the cred).

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm 99% sure constexpr works here but I'm revising a coding standard in light of template variables' behavior here and I need standardese. One might argue that static_assert only proves that it works in the tested cases.

Comment: Actually I'm becoming more pessimistic about static_assert as a proof-of-concept here. Someone with more compiler/standard knowledge might want to chime in.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but I believe you could say that a passing static_assert is only be asserting the ordering that the compiler arbitrarily chose for that particular build; this situation would be equivalent to TSIOF except that at least you get a compile time error. In any case at this point I see the static_assert as *potentially* misleading. At best it could be used to guarantee the ordering that you got from the compiler... until you forget the static_assert.

Comment: constexpr can't have dynamic initialization, by definition

Comment: @PasserBy The original wording of my question was not clear enough. Please see the update.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [basic.start.static](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.start.static):

> *Constant initialization* is performed if a variable or temporary
>   object with **static** or thread storage duration is initialized by a
>   constant initializer for the entity.

In your code:

```
template<class T> static constexpr T a = 41; // constant initialization
```

is doing *constant initialization* which makes:

```
template<class T> static constexpr T b = a<T>+1;
```

be initialized with `42` due to the templates' *constant evaluation*.

which states that (From [expr.const/8.7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.const#8.7)):

> a variable whose name appears as a potentially constant evaluated
>   expression that is either a *constexpr variable* or is of non-volatile
>   const-qualified integral type or of reference type.

Thus, it is guaranteed the output is always `"success"`ful.

**NOTE** From [basic.start.static/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.start.static#2):

> Together, *zero-initialization* and *constant initialization* are called
>   **static initialization**

-- *not* dynamic initialization

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have updated my question to clarify exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>[Note that throughout this post, `a<T>` and `b<T>` are shortened to `a` and `b`, respectively.]</sup>

[`[expr.const/3]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.const#3) states that:

> A variable is *usable in constant expressions* after its initializing declaration is encountered if it is a constexpr variable, or it is of reference type or of const-qualified integral or enumeration type, and its initializer is a constant initializer.

Thus, `a` will be usable during `b`'s initialisation, due to the `constexpr` specifier.  `constexpr` is fully applicable both for variables and variable templates, as stated in the first sentence of [`[dcl.constexpr/1]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.constexpr#1).

> The `constexpr` specifier shall be applied only to the definition of a variable or variable template or the declaration of a function or function template.

Thus, a variable or variable template declared `constexpr` is usable in constant expressions (including the initialisation of other `constexpr` variables) after its own initialisation, with the value specified in its initialisation (due to constant initialisation being implictly guaranteed by `constexpr`).

---

If we wish to explore the second option in `[expr.const/3]` rather than relying on the "`constexpr` means yes" clause, that one will also lead to `a` being usable during `b`'s initialisation, albeit by a more circuitous route that involves delving into multiple parts of the standard and piecing together the implicit guarantees.

First, would come the question of whether `a` has a *constant initializer*.  To determine whether it has a constant initializer, we can consult [`[expr.const/2]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.const#2), which reads (note omitted):

> A *constant initializer* for a variable or temporary object o is an initializer for which interpreting its full-expression as a *constant-expression* results in a constant expression, except that if o is an object, such an initializer may also invoke constexpr constructors for o and its subobjects even if those objects are of non-literal class types.

We have two explicit guarantees that the initialiser's full-expression is a constant expression, both from [`[dcl.constexpr/9]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.constexpr#9): `a` is implicitly `const`, and the full-expression *not* being a constant expression would be an error.

> A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as const.
>   Such an object shall have literal type and shall be initialized.
>   In any `constexpr` variable declaration, the full-expression of the initialization shall be a constant expression.

This, by extension, also means that (as of C++14), `a` will *not* be subject zero initialisation ([`[basic.start.static/2]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.start.static#2), irrelevant parts omitted):

> *Constant initialization* is performed if a variable or temporary object with static or thread storage duration is initialized by a constant initializer ([expr.const]) for the entity.
>   If constant initialization is not performed, a variable with static storage duration ([basic.stc.static]) or thread storage duration ([basic.stc.thread]) is zero-initialized ([dcl.init]).

To verify that `a` has the correct value after initialisation, if we want to be *really* thorough, we could then look at [`[intro.execution/9]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.execution#9):

> Every value computation and side effect associated with a full-expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated.

As we know that `a`'s initialisation is a full-expression, we are implicitly guaranteed that `a` will have been assigned the value `41` by the end of its full-expression, before the next full-expression (including other initialisations) in sequence is evaluated.  By combining this with `[expr.const/3]` and `[basic.start.static/2]`, we are thus guaranteed that (as with the `constexpr` clause), `a` is usable in constant expressions encountered after its own initialisation, such as `b`'s initialisation, and also guaranteed that `a == 41 && a != 0`.